# Luis batch testing not showing custom entities

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

[image]I am using batch testing in luis, the intent part is working fine but the custom made entities are not even showing up on the list. Is there anything I am doing wrong.
BTW the entities are working fine in single testing
Thanks for the help

Comment: please add screenshots

Comment: I have added a screen shot

Comment: As you can see my entities are not even getting listed

Comment: Just a guess, is it only showing the entity used in the batch test? Does you batch test only use one entity?

Comment: No Berry, I have used almost all the entities in the batch test

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the inconvenience. This is a known issue and we are working around the fix and will be deployed soon. Will update the answer again once we fix it. Thanks for your patience.

**Update:** The issue has been fixed!!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Also, the same problem is occurring while exporting the app as a JSon. Hope that gets cleared too. In my exported JSON the entities values are empty in the utterances branch